# Could not find declaration file even after creating .d.ts file

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I got this error with typescript

`src/usecases/Reports/GenerateReportUseCase.ts(7,23): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'convert-json-to-csv'.`

There are no typings for this package, so i just get an error when doing `npm i --save-dev @types/convert-json-to-csv`

I have this folder structure:

[image: File structure]

Inside index.d.ts i have this:

`declare module 'convert-json-to-csv';`

and inside the tsconfig i have this:

`"typeRoots": ["./src/types"],`

Where am i going wrong?

Comment: The issue with the module `convert-json-to-csv` is that it doesn't have any built-in types, nor any `@types` module. This is probably because of the low downloads.

Answer (score 0):

The issue i had was that my server is using ts-node instead of tsc. In order to get the module declarations to be recognised i had to change my start script to the following : `"start": "nodemon --legacy-watch --files"`

Note the `--files`, this is what was added to fix this issue.